# Cannot login to Admin panel after deploying Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework

So I deployed a Django rest framework to Heroku and after setting up PostgreSQL, running the migrate command and also creating a superuser, I cannot seem to login into my Django admin panel. Below is my settings.py file.

```
Django settings for ptracker project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!


SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', 'trakkkr.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    'tracker.apps.TrackerConfig',
    'corsheaders',

    # installed apps
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Account'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ptracker.urls'

CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.getenv('CELERY_BROKER_URL')

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ptracker.wsgi.application'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY': 'error',
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

CORS_ALLOWED_ALL_ORIGINS = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")


# EMAIL CONFIGURATION
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get("EMAIL_USER")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("EMAIL_PASSWORD")

# REDIS CONFIGURATION
broker_url = os.getenv('CELERY_BROKER_URL')
result_backend = os.getenv('RESULT_BACKEND')
accept_content = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
result_serializer = 'json'
timezone = 'Africa/Lagos'


django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

I have hosted like 2 projects on Heroku before and I have never experienced this, would so much appreciate if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser` you ran this command to create superuser?

Comment: Hi @Pradip, yeah I did.... I accessed the user through shell console and the user was created.

Comment: Now you can login or not in admin panel? If not  then recheck your Url.

Comment: I still cannot login.... My URL is correct,  even created a new superuser to be sure I didn't make a mistake when creating the first superuser, still the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. I did the following to the solve the issue

- ran `python manage.py shell` to be able to use the python shell
- Imported my custom user model by running `from appname.models import ModelName` if you are using the built-in User model, just do `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`
- used `user = ModelName.objects.get(username="superuser's username")` or `User.objects.get(username="superuser's username")` if you are using the built-in user model to get the superuser I created
- I then changed the superuser's password by doing `user.set_password('newpassword')` and then `user.save()`.

Go back to your admin's login page and enter the superuser's credentials again, you should be logged into the admin panel.

I hope this helps someone with similar issue.